# Why does log4j2 not log to a file after packaging as a jar in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, log4j2

I'm new to java, and I've written a simple java program to test a few things out before attempting the same things with the more complicated app that I'm almost ready to deploy.  I'm using Eclipse, and I've exported the package as a jar file.  When I run the jar file, everything appears to be working correctly.  Log4j2 is logging properly to the console, and the application is doing what I want it to.  The problem I'm having is that the log files are not being created / written to.  This all works correctly when I'm running the app from Eclipse.  What I was expecting is that I could move the .jar file anywhere I wanted.  That I could then execute the app and a logs folder would be created in that same directory and a trace log and an error log would be created and written to.

Here is the log4j2.xml that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="trace-log" fileName="${log-path}/logging-trace.log" filePattern="${log-path}/logging-trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/logging-error.log" filePattern="${log-path}/logging-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="multithreadTest" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="trace-log" level="debug"/>
            <appender-ref ref="error-log" level="error"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here are the contents of the manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ log4j-api-2.5.jar log4j-core-2.5.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: multithreadTest.RunTest
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

I'm executing the application like this:

java -jar mtest.jar

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add ref to all your loogers

```
<Root level="info" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="trace-log"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="error-log"/>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I posted what I changed in another comment.  It corrected my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dom farr.  I changed this:

```
    <Logger name="multithreadTest" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="trace-log" level="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="error-log" level="error"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
```

to this:

```
<Logger name="multithreadTest" level="info" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="trace-log" level="debug"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="error-log" level="error"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="console-log" level="debug"/>
</Logger>
```

and it is now working correctly.  I'm not sure why.  I guess I need to read more about the difference between the two.  Not sure why it would work correctly in Eclipse if this is incorrect XML.  Anyway, it is working now.  Thanks again.